# List Object Reference null

Tags: c#, instance, nullreferenceexception, initializer-list

I have a ProfileVM that includes:

```
    public class ProfileVM
    {
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> JobsList { get; set; }

    }
```

As I have a partial view that allow us to update the User account details, everything works fine till loading the view. The view is loaded and the DropDownList too.

Here my code of the view:

```
[...]

<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="form-group floating-label enable-floating-label show-label">
                                                <label asp-for="User.JobFunction"> Job <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <select class="form-control select2" id="JobFunction" name="User.JobFunction">
                                                    <option value="">Select a job</option>
                                                    @foreach (var job in Model.JobsList)
                                                    {
                                                        <option value="@job.Value" selected="@(job.Value == Model.User.JobFunction)">@job.Text</option>
                                                    }
                                                </select>
</div>
</div>
```

The controller is the following:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Profile(string Id)
        {
            if (Id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var userFromDb = _context.ApplicationUser.Find(Id);

            if (userFromDb == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var profileVM = new ProfileVM
            {
                User = userFromDb,
                JobsList = _unitOfWork.Job.GetJobsList() // Assuming you have a method to populate the job options
            };

            return View(profileVM);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Profile(ProfileVM profileVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                if (profileVM.JobsList == null)
                {
                    List<Job> jobs = _context.Jobs.ToList();
                    List<SelectListItem> jobsList = jobs.Select(job => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = job.JobDescription_EN,
                        Text = job.JobDescription_EN
                    }).ToList();

                    profileVM.JobsList = jobsList;
                }

                                

                //Save changes to the user
                _unitOfWork.User.Update(profileVM.User);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), "Home");
            }

            return View(profileVM);
        }
```

The problem is that I lose the JobsList instance when clicking on "Update Button".
So I added the following code to assign another time jobsList list to profileVM.JobsList:

```
                if (profileVM.JobsList == null)
                {
                    List<Job> jobs = _context.Jobs.ToList();
                    List<SelectListItem> jobsList = jobs.Select(job => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = job.JobDescription_EN,
                        Text = job.JobDescription_EN
                    }).ToList();

                    profileVM.JobsList = jobsList;
                }
```

What am I doing wrong as profileVM.JobsList remains null and the following error :

"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

on:
@foreach (var job in Model.JobsList)
{
@job.Text
}

?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: See this link: https://code-maze.com/select-tag-helper-aspnetcore/                      
    Can modify your view's select tag as follows:                                                     
  <select class="form-control select2" asp-for="User.JobFunction" asp-items="@Model.JobsList">
    <option>Please Select</option>
</select>

Comment: Thank you so much, I will study it :). The view select tag works fine. Now I have to adapt your documentation with my controller code.